# Finding variables passed to jinja2 from sphinx

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx

I am trying to create a template in sphinx. My intention is not to use the basic template, but to build a new one from scratch. However there is very little (/no) documentation about what variables are passed from sphinx into the templates.

I would like to dump all of the variables that are being passed to the template from sphinx. (ideally within a template as my python knowledge isn't good!)

Comment: this link may be useful for you: http://pbpython.com/pdf-reports.html

Comment: @dot.Py that does look interesting! thank you I shall investigate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sphinx documentation provides a [list of most variables](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html#global-variables) that are available in templates.
You find additional variables - of which most are passed on by docutils - in [this dictionary (Sphinx source code)](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/v1.4.5/sphinx/builders/html.py#L995).

In addition, you can use the [html_theme_options](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-html_theme_options) dictionary in the `conf.py` file to add custom configuration variables to your own template.

The custom configuration variables need to be accessed with the prefix `theme_`.

For example, if you define your custom variables as follows:

```
html_theme_options = {
    'pdf_path': '/docs/MyDocs.pdf'
}
```

, you can access the `pdf_path` variable as `{{theme_pdf_path}}`.

Alternatively, the custom theme variables can be defined in your theme's [theme.conf](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/theme.conf) file. In our example, you would add the line `pdf_path = /docs/MyDocs.pdf`.